# Does gmpy2 have "e=2.1718..." constant?

Tags: python, gmp, gmpy

It does have Euler–Mascheroni constant, but I cannot find whether it has exp(1) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not. `gmpy2` only provides the constants that are provided with the [`MPFR`](http://www.mpfr.org/) library. `exp(1)` would be the best option.